# Printer not showing Duplex Printing Option in Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: kubuntu, printing, canon, cups-lpd, duplex-printing

I have recently brought a printer and connected to my windows PC and duplex was fairly usable and tried installing the same in kubuntu 22.04. The printer installed successfully using CUPS and prints very well. But the problem I faced is that I did not get duplex option at all.

My Printer-Cannon Pixma G4000 Series

[image: Print Dialog]

In two sided print drop-menu no options are available .

How can get back the property to print duplex again.

THankyou in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Printers are managed by CUPS, the Common Unix Printing System.

Access the CUPS control panels by pointing your browser to `http://localhost:631`.

Click on the `Printers` tab at the top of the page.

Click on your printer.

From the `Administration` dropdown lisr, select "`Set Default Options`".

Set **`Double-Sided Printing`** to `Long Edge (Standard)`.